# Why do I get an error Unexpected keyword 'new' in my Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

> When I run the  npm test command in a Jest envroment I get following error Unexpected keyword 'new'
> The error report looks like

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/steinko/development/TutorialKubernetesClient/JestConfig/cluster.test.js: Unexpected keyword 'new'. (5:11)

      3 |
      4 | it('should exist a kubeconfig', {
    > 5 |     expect(new kubernetesClient.KubeConfig()).not.toBeNull();
        |            ^
      6 | })

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:134:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:129:17)
      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:78:17)
      at Parser.checkReservedWord (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2386:12)
      at Parser.parseIdentifierName (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2336:12)
      at Parser.parseIdentifier (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2306:23)
      at Parser.parseBindingAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:299:17)
      at Parser.parseMaybeDefault (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:370:25)
      at Parser.parseAssignableListItem (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:346:23)
      at Parser.parseBindingList (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:336:24)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 sum.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.069 s
```

> The test that fails look like this

```
const kubernetesClient = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

it('should exist a kubeconfig', {
    expect(new kubernetesClient.KubeConfig()).not.toBeNull();
})
```

> I have setup the Jest enviroment by:
>
> 1. installing Jets

```
npm install --save-dev jest
```

> 2. and generated the basic configuraion file by

```
jest --init
```

> With following configuration
> The following questions will help Jest to create a suitable configuration for your project

```
✔ Would you like to use Typescript for the configuration file? … no
✔ Choose the test environment that will be used for testing › jsdom (browser-like)
✔ Do you want Jest to add coverage reports? … yes
✔ Which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage? › v8
✔ Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test? … yes
```

> When I run the test follwing error occure

> test
> jest

```
PASS  ./sum.test.js
 FAIL  ./cluster.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/steinko/development/TutorialKubernetesClient/JestConfig/cluster.test.js: Unexpected keyword 'new'. (5:11)

      3 |
      4 | it('should exist a kubeconfig', {
    > 5 |     expect(new kubernetesClient.KubeConfig()).not.toBeNull();
        |            ^
      6 | })

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:134:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:129:17)
      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:78:17)
      at Parser.checkReservedWord (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2386:12)
      at Parser.parseIdentifierName (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2336:12)
      at Parser.parseIdentifier (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:2306:23)
      at Parser.parseBindingAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:299:17)
      at Parser.parseMaybeDefault (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:370:25)
      at Parser.parseAssignableListItem (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:346:23)
      at Parser.parseBindingList (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/lval.js:336:24)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 sum.js   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.069 s
```

> What do I have todo to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
it('should exist a kubeconfig', {
```

should be

```
it('should exist a kubeconfig', function() {
```